# React in Django or React as a standalone?

Tags: django, reactjs

I have been researching how to create django react application and the best way to go about implementing it. From this link on creating a django react app states a few way to go about implementing it.

One way is to generate a webpack and using django to load the webpack another is to run it as 2 separate applications.

What are the obvious benefits of "React in its own “frontend” Django app: load a single HTML template and let React manage the frontend" vs "Django REST as a standalone API + React as a standalone SPA"

Because I do not see a need of generating a webpack and loading the application in django template where you could create a standalone react app and use Django REST for communication?

Comment: React isn't standalone. You need to use nodejs with that.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you would gain by splitting your frontend and your backend is modularity. With your application logic completely separated from your user interface, you have a slightly more modular web application. Modularity aids in a number of things, including testing, readability, and maintainability.

Also with a separate API, your backend logic can be reused by any anyone or any frontend be it a mobile app or anything you could imagine even your CLI.

Your goal would be to include the final bundle of your create react app in a Django page if I understood correctly ?